# Unmounting /var/lib/container/storage/overlay/.../merged: invalid argument error

Tags: podman, linux-containers, unmount

I have been trying to remove SC4S container in podman and it throws the below error.

```
WARN[0000] Unmounting container "SC4S" while attempting to delete storage: 
unmounting "/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/.../merged": invalid 
argument Error: removing storage for container "SC4S": unmounting 
"/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/.../merged": invalid argument
```

I tried removing the image (`podman rmi -f imageid`) and I receive the same unmount error above

Usually we will try to unmount `/var/lib/containers` with umount and try rebuilding the image after removing the image

Note that even `podman unmount` didn't work. It throws no containers found in that ID.

I'm looking for any solution without unmounting the directory `/var/lib/containers`

The container only show when I use `--external` tag as below
`podman ps --external`
But not when I use `podman ps -a`

Are there any ways to unmount it or remove the container without unmounting the path ?